# ds-math-sub-underflow error at remove liquidity from uniswap

Tags: uniswap, liquidity, ds-math-sub-underflow

I am trying to write a contract to remove liquidity from uniswap

In below code I have tried to use both functions of uniswap that is `removeLiquidity` and `removeLiquidityETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens` but none of them works, and I get the error:

```
Fail with error 'ds-math-sub-underflow'
```

Transaction link: https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xbb97851b4218dfb21405ca273409b41b5b0fff15fd8a0446d6b966a41388d515

Uniswap pair: 0x430Ca100e350c1A4C0DA87fd104aB3d76A69C245

```
function removeAllLiquidity(address _wallet) external {
    address pair = IUniswapV2Factory(FACTORY).getPair(GARY, WETH);

    uint liquidity = IERC20(pair).balanceOf(_wallet);
    safeApprove(IERC20(pair), ROUTER, liquidity);

    (uint amountA, uint amountB) = IUniswapV2Router(ROUTER).removeLiquidity(
        GARY,
        WETH,
        liquidity,
        1,
        1,
        _wallet,
        block.timestamp
    );
}

function remove(address _wallet) external {
    address pair = IUniswapV2Factory(FACTORY).getPair(GARY, WETH);

    uint liquidity = IERC20(pair).balanceOf(_wallet);
    safeApprove(IERC20(pair), ROUTER, liquidity);

    (uint amountB) = IUniswapV2Router(ROUTER).removeLiquidityETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        GARY,
        liquidity,
        1,
        1,
        _wallet,
        block.timestamp
    );
    
}
```

I have also approved the uniswap router address from user wallet to use the Lp tokens.

Can someone please help?

Comment: hey, did you figure it out?